# Why my e-mail address is still operational even after I have resigned?

Tags: resignation

I have been checking my e-mail address, and it still exists, whereas all my colleagues, who resigned during the same period, have their accounts closed.

Indeed, my resignation wasn't very well welcomed, but I left nonetheless.

Is it risky to have my account still open?

Comment: By checking do you mean you are logging in and reading/sending emails?

Comment: Did you use your work account for anything other than work?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep, I use mailtester.com.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, no I didn't.

Comment: The question is very unspecific. Individual e-mail accounts being operational can have a multitude of reasons and a multitude of consequences.

Comment: If you are concerned about it, you can contact your old employer and let them know. What they do about it is up to them, though. It isn't your email address, it's theirs.

Comment: @Sascha, it is a clear question: why everybody else, who resigned and were beyond their notice have closed accounts except for mine?

Comment: Are you working in the same dept? Are you working for the same Boss? Is the secretary different? Are the circumstances (role etc) between you and you colleagues identical? Is your IT otherwise very systematic in handling such things? are there IT guidelines regarding the deactivation of the adresses? Did you have a function where the company may not want the customer to know that you are gone immediatly? Did your account have public calenders in exchange attached?

Comment: `whereas all my colleagues, who resigned during the same period, have their accounts closed` after how much time there accounts were closed? Did you resing a few day ago?

Comment: @Syndicate, only your employer can answer that question. No one here can.

Comment: There are two ? marks and not actually your account.  VTC

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing to remember: **it's not your e-mail address**. It's your employer's e-mail address which just happens to have your name in the local part. As such, they can do whatever they like with it, and if they want to keep it open  they can keep it open. So long as no personal information is being sent to that address (which it shouldn't be, because it's not your e-mail address), there's no risk to you.

None of your business what happens to it, just move on to your next job.

Answer (score 1):

It could still be open because they want to keep it active enough to forward new messages to a replacement. They will on a future date turn it off.

Or they could have missed it. Recently where I work IT turned off the wrong email address. An employee retire and when they went to disable the email account they picked a similar name from a list. It took days to get it fixed.

Unless you were counting on some messages bouncing back, this should not be your concern.

Comment: I had a few people send emails to a company address I still had access to after leaving a company. I would already reply back with something along the lines of "I am no longer with the company, you will want to talk to Xyz." and CC Xyz or include their email address. I wasn't the correct person to talk to even if I had so worked there, but that seemed to be the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the address only for work, it should not be a problem. They may be keeping each former employee address open as long as they get any incoming e-mail on it. That could vary among addresses.

Comment: My colleagues, those who resigned, they all had seen their email addresses closed.